# ESLint: Definition for rule 'no-misleading-character-classes' was not found

Tags: node.js, eslint

After making the switch from TSLint to ESLint, and defining all of the rules that I wanted to use, I ran ESLint for the first time and received the following error:

```
$> npx eslint /path/to/my-file.ts

/path/to/my-file.ts
  1:1  error  Definition for rule 'no-misleading-character-classes' was not found  no-misleading-character-classes

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

This error is thrown regardless of the input file (even for empty files), and always occurs at position 1:1.

I'm currently using ESLint version v7.32.0, and this `.eslintrc.json` appears to be the minimum sufficient config file to product the problem:

```
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "project": "./tsconfig.json",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-misleading-character-classes": ["error"]
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? How do I prevent this error from being thrown (apart from disabling the rule)?

Comment: It seems to be [`'no-misleading-character-class'`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-misleading-character-class)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty  lovely. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A tale as old as time - a spelling mistake:

The rule is not:

```
no-misleading-character-classes
```

but rather:

```
no-misleading-character-class
```